# How do I delete/remove a home screen web link?

Tags: iphone, ios, icon, mobile-safari

I recently created two web links using Safari's "Add to Home Screen" and now it seems to be impossible to remove them.

The following has been attempted (from http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1395687&seqNum=9):

> To remove a Web clip, tap-and-hold for a few seconds on it, until all
>   the icons start to wiggle. You’ll see a little X in the upper-left
>   corner of each Web clip (and app that can be removed). Simply tap the
>   little X and then tap Delete from the dialog that appears. The Web
>   clip will disappear, and your remaining icons will reshuffle. Tap the
>   Home button to stop the icons from wiggling and lock them in place.

That **X** does **not** show up on my icons.. I can drag them around, even to other pages, group them in folders and bring them out again, but not delete them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web clips added by a profile can be set to not be able to be deleted with the X, therefore hiding the X when in edit mode. To remove a web clip added in this way, you need to remove the profile from Settings → General → Profiles.

You can also try disabling restrictions if they are on. Go to Settings → General → Restrictions and switch it off, then try removing the web clips.

Comment: I have no profiles, but found **restrictions**. Settings → General → Restrictions (Disable Restrictions), remove the icons, reenable restrictions is the way to go. Since your suggestion helped me, you can add this to your answer and I'll accept. :p Thanks!